# Is it possible to return just one field when struct initialized and called in other package?

Tags: go, struct

Let's say I have a struct structured like this in matrix package

```
package matrix

type Matrix struct {
  rows     int
  cols     int
  isSquare bool
  Element  [][]float64
}
```

we know that when we initialize `Matrix` in other package we can only assign values ​​to the `Element` field only, because `rows`,`cols`,and `isSquare` are not exported and just for internal use inside package `Matrix`.

and when we initialize in main package it will look like this:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/example/blabla/matrix"
)

func main() {
    m := matrix.Matrix{
            Element: [][]float64{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}
         }

    fmt.Println(m) // the output : {0 0 false [[1 2] [3 4]]}
}
```

the example above returning the `Element` following with other fields (with default value).

#### What I want is:

How to make the struct just return only one field and explicitly refer to `matrix.Matrix.Element` when `matrix.Matrix` called in other package, is it possible?

```
func main() {
    m := matrix.Matrix{Element: [][]float64{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}}

    fmt.Println(m) // i want this to just return [[1 2] [3 4]] (as Element field)
                   // and explicitly refer to a matrix.Matrix.Element field, without other fields involved
}
```

Comment: Have a helper function to print only the `Element` field.

Comment: Is your goal to change the behavior of what `matrix.Matrix` prints when it is given as an argument to `fmt.Println`, or is the goal to give the user of the code something other than a `matrix.Matrix` when the constructor is called?

Answer (score 4):

You can add a `String()` method to your `Matrix` struct. For example

```golang
type Matrix struct {
    rows     int
    cols     int
    isSquare bool
    Element  [][]float64
}

func (m Matrix) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", m.Element)
}
```

You can find a working example [here](https://play.golang.org/p/ZFsuMfUwMh_f).

Answer (score 0):

> how to make the struct just return only one field and explicitly refer to matrix.Matrix.Element when matrix.Matrix called in other package, is it possible?

No.

(But there really is no need for it. Your use of matrix.Matrix is just printing it. If you want to customize how package fmt does this: Provide a String methods. Note that you did not and you cannot "call" matrix.Matrix. Types cannot be called.)

Comment: oh i see, so i should build a Stringer interface inside matrix pakcage right?, but the `m` variable strill hold the actual values

Comment: @RidwanMaulanaTanjung I admit  I do not know what you mean by this. Add a String  method to Matrix.